# How to sendkeys in tinymce where iframe is dynamic

Tags: c#, iframe, selenium-webdriver, tinymce

How do I send keys to 3 `TinyMCE` fields on the same screen, and the `Iframe ID` is dynamic using selenium webdriver `c#`?

The code below works if the `id` of the frame was not dynamic:

```
        Driver.SwitchTo().Frame("ea05aa0a-668b-4a08-9770-221262e77b29_ifr");
        Driver.FindElement(By.Id("tinymce")).SendKeys("hello 1");
        Driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();

        Driver.SwitchTo().Frame("c45c67ae-d33b-4ec3-be2e-12a6d40b14ab_ifr");
        Driver.FindElement(By.Id("tinymce")).SendKeys("hello 2");
        Driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();


        Driver.SwitchTo().Frame("bbfce656-ea5e-4f01-b409-437d0c60e187_ifr");
        Driver.FindElement(By.Id("tinymce")).SendKeys("hello 3");
        Driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

Code field `TinyMCE` 1:

```
<div id="mce_44" class="mce-edit-area mce-container mce-panel mce-stack-layout-item" tabindex="-1" hidefocus="1" style="border-width: 1px 0px 0px;">

<iframe id="ea05aa0a-668b-4a08-9770-221262e77b29_ifr" frameborder="0" src="javascript:""" allowtransparency="true" title="Área de texto formatado. Pressione ALT-F9 para exibir o menu…a exibir a barra de ferramentas ou ALT-0 para exibir a ajuda" style="width: 100%; height: 100px; display: block;">
    #document
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html webdriver="true">
            <head></head>
            <body id="tinymce" class="mce-content-body " contenteditable="true" onload="window.parent.tinymce.get('ea05aa0a-668b-4a08-9770-221262e77b29').fire('load');" spellcheck="false"></body>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Already answered here? http://stackoverflow.com/a/24061054/3124333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can try this only if that's the only iFrame on the Page ideally it'll be something like

```
   IWebElement iFrameElement = driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//*[contains(@class,'edit-  
   area')]/child:::iframe"));
   Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(iFrameElement);
```

Or Use a Different Xpath Expression to Math the iFrame something like

```
//*[contains(@class,'edit-area')]/preceding:::iframe[contains(@id,'ifr')]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Alternatively, select the iframe index: <code> Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0);, .Frame(1), and .Frame(2)...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for switching once then, and perform all actions on the frame:

```
Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(Driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//iframe[contains(@title, 'Área de texto formatado.')]")));
```