# How to put a text into the textfield using selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

i'm using selenium 2.46.0 and python 3.4
I want to put the string "Hello, world!" into the textfield for creating new letter.
Am i doing this the right way? I try to switch the frame and find the right element to put the text into it.
My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://mail.ru/')
browser.find_element_by_name('Login').clear()
browser.find_element_by_name('Login').send_keys('selenium90')
browser.find_element_by_name('Password').clear()
browser.find_element_by_name('Password').send_keys('pythonrocks')
browser.find_element_by_id('mailbox__auth__button').click()
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('a.b-toolbar__btn').click()
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('textarea.js-input:nth-child(5)').send_keys('07ufo@mail.ru')

browser.switch_to_frame(browser.find_element_by_id('compose_462_composeEditor_ifr'))
browser.find_element_by_class_name('mceContentBody').send_keys('Hello, world!')
```

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElement
Exception: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"compose_462_composeEditor_ifr"}

I tried:

```
iframe = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[frameindex]
browser.switch_to_frame(iframe)
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('body.tinymce').send_keys('hoo')
```

But it did not help

i added a screenshot of tree:
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selenium and wordpress: New post test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23999777/selenium-and-wordpress-new-post-test)

Answer (score 2):

The id of that element is dynamically generated! Try something like:

```
browser.switch_to_frame(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//frame[contains(@id, "composeEditor_ifr")]'))
```

Comment: SiKing, hi, i tried to use it. But it did not help.