# JQuery: How to set FOCUS to a TinyMCE editor?

Tags: jquery, selenium, tinymce

I'm trying to add text to **TinyMCE** using **SELENIUM**.  I've been able to add text using this code:

```
$('iframe').last().contents().find('body').text('401c484b-68e4-4bf2-a13d-2a564acddc04');
```

The **TinyMCE** editor is displaying the **GUID**. However, when Selenium click the submit button, I'm getting an error: `Please, enter a text.`.

I've noticed that, while Selenium is running, I just need to click (manually) on the **TinyMCE** then, when the update button is clicked, the text is returned.

So how do I click the **TinyMCE** using **javascript** or **jQuery**?

Comment: Don't know about jQuery. Since you tagged this with "Selenium" I will point you to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24061054/3124333

Comment: @SiKing, the link you provided worked well. There is a small modification I had to add. I had to click the outside the iframe. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer came from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23999777/selenium-and-wordpress-new-post-test/24061054#24061054) @SiKing pointed me to.

```
public void EnterTextInTinyMCE(int n, string noteText, string escapeElementCss)
    {
        driver.SwitchTo().Frame(n - 1);
        IWebElement body = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//body"));
        body.Click();
        Wait(3);

        IJavaScriptExecutor jse = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
        jse.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].innerHTML = '" + noteText + "'", body);

        driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();

        Wait(3); 
        ClickLinkByFullCSS(escapeElementCss); //--- I ADDED THIS LINE TO FORCE 
                                              //--- THE IFRAME ELEMENT TO LOSE FOCUS
    }
```

`ClickLinkByFullCSS();` is just a method that I defined in the base class and `escapeElementCss` is just an element outside the `iframe`. I chose the title bar because it's just a div that doesn't have any button, to avoid clicking on an element that might produce an event.

In fact, switching back to DefaultContent is pulling the focus away from the editor. So I just client to an element outside the editor. That force the editor to lose focus and the update was successful.